# select rows that having dependencies to other rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, rows

I've a table having data as:

```
C1    || C2  
-----------------
1     || a   
1     || b   
1     || c   
2     || a   
2     || b  
2     || c   
3     || a   
3     || b   
4     || c   
4     || d   
5     || c   
6     || a
```

I've to select all C1 personal numbers that have C2 `b` or `c` and non a value. Suggestions ?

Like only -> C1 = 4 and 5

Comment: You want just C1, or the two rows (C1,4) and (C1,5)?

Comment: the comment from ughai is the right :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer uses similar technique as per Gordon Lindoff's answer.

You can use `GROUP BY` with `having` like this.

```
select c1
from table t
group by c1
having sum(case when c2 in ('b', 'c') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
and sum(case when c2 = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `having` clause to count the other values.  If the count is 0, then you want the `c1` value:

```
select c1
from table t
group by c1
having sum(case when c2 in ('b', 'c') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Correct technique, but wrong criteria ;-) 'b' or 'c' shall exist, 'a' must not exist.

Comment: your having is a little incorrect `having sum(case when c2 in ('b', 'c') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and sum(case when c2 in ('a') then 1 else 0 end) = 0`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . It was correct as I interpreted the question -- now I see what "non a value" is supposed to mean.  I took it to mean "not any other value".